# Types which can be displayed as string

Tags: c#, types, casting

I need to collect all Types in C# which can be converted to string. 
My List so far contains:

- string
- byte
- sbyte
- char
- int
- uint
- long
- ulong
- short
- ushort

Please help me collect more.

Comment: None of those types can be casted to a string. I think you should revise the vocabulary and what casting means in .NET.

Answer (score 6):

Of the types that you mentioned only `string` can be truly *casted* to `string`. There are no other types, and there could be no other types like that, because `System.String` class is *sealed*.

As far as *converting*, not casting, to `string` goes, every single type in .NET has a conversion to `string` available, because `ToString` method is defined on `System.Object`, the root class of all objects in .NET. In particular, all primitive types in .NET provide suitable overrides for their `ToString` method.